# R gsub encounters encoding error after update from R 4.2.1 to R 4.3.0

Tags: r, string

My R 4.2.1 script runs into an error after updating to R 4.3.0 when trying to do the following string replacement:

```
maakasutus <- c("P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xf5llukultuurid, P\xfcsikultuurid", "P\xfcsikultuurid", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xfcsirohumaa", "P\xf5llukultuurid", "P\xfcsirohumaa")

maakasutus <- gsub(pattern = c("\xfc"), replacement = c("ü"), x = maakasutus)
```

It throws the error:

```
Error in gsub(pattern = "\xfc", replacement = "ü", x = maakasutus) : 
  'pattern' is invalid.
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub(pattern = c("\\xfc"), replacement = c("ü"), x = maakasutus) :
  unable to translate 'P<fc>sirohumaa' to a wide string
```

or alternatively `unable to translate '<fc>' to a wide string`

I tried double escaping the xfc-term `gsub(pattern = c("\\xfc"), replacement = c("ü"), x = maakasutus)`, which slightly changes the error message to "input string 1 is invalid", but doesn't help a lot.

Originally it's Estonian text in a shapefile, containing ü, õ and the like. I can neither change the shapefile nor the process of reading in, since sf:::st_read does the job on it's own. So I felt quite lucky when it worked out under R 4.2.1, because I don't know a lot about string manipulation. Therefore I'm stuck now.

Comment: This is helpful: https://blog.r-project.org/2022/06/27/why-to-avoid-%5Cx-in-regular-expressions/index.html

Comment: but actually I couldn't find the solution...

Comment: adding `useBytes=TRUE` to the `gsub` cal seems to work .. although the link above states "It is not recommended to disable the newly added checks via useBytes,"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the issue is with the encoding. You do not have to substitute. Try the following:

```
iconv(maakasutus, 'latin1')
 [1] "Püsirohumaa"                   "Püsirohumaa"                  
 [3] "Põllukultuurid"                "Püsirohumaa"                  
 [5] "Põllukultuurid"                "Põllukultuurid"               
 [7] "Püsirohumaa"                   "Püsirohumaa"                  
 [9] "Püsirohumaa"                   "Põllukultuurid"               
[11] "Põllukultuurid, Püsikultuurid" "Püsikultuurid"                
[13] "Põllukultuurid"                "Püsirohumaa"                  
[15] "Püsirohumaa"                   "Põllukultuurid"               
[17] "Püsirohumaa"                   "Püsirohumaa"                  
[19] "Püsirohumaa"                   "Põllukultuurid"               
[21] "Püsirohumaa"                   "Põllukultuurid"               
[23] "Püsirohumaa"
```

or even

```
 Encoding(x) <- 'latin1'
```

where `x` is your string.

Answer (score 1):

Add `useBytes=TRUE` like this (see `?gsub`):

```
gsub(pattern = "\xfc", replacement = "ü", x = maakasutus, useBytes = TRUE)
```

giving

```
 [1] "Püsirohumaa"                      "Püsirohumaa"                     
 [3] "P\xf5llukultuurid"                "Püsirohumaa"                     
 [5] "P\xf5llukultuurid"                "P\xf5llukultuurid"               
 [7] "Püsirohumaa"                      "Püsirohumaa"                     
 [9] "Püsirohumaa"                      "P\xf5llukultuurid"               
[11] "P\xf5llukultuurid, Püsikultuurid" "Püsikultuurid"                   
[13] "P\xf5llukultuurid"                "Püsirohumaa"                     
[15] "Püsirohumaa"                      "P\xf5llukultuurid"               
[17] "Püsirohumaa"                      "Püsirohumaa"                     
[19] "Püsirohumaa"                      "P\xf5llukultuurid"               
[21] "Püsirohumaa"                      "P\xf5llukultuurid"               
[23] "Püsirohumaa"
```